# System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen method not found

Tags: c#

I've added reference to `System.Drawing` to my project, but that method just doesn't seem to be there. It's not in the autocomplete hint, it doesn't work when fully typed. Visual Studio just keeps pretending it's not a real thing, though clearly, it has to be:

[System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38ft55b.aspx)

All I'm trying to do is make a screenshot. What am I missing?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that you don't have an _instance_.

Comment: `The type 'System.Drawing.Graphics' has no constructors defined`

Comment: It's constructor is private, but it has static methods that return instances.

Comment: post the code you are using

Comment: Graphics.CopyFromScreen Method exist in  
.NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an *instance* of the `Graphics` class that draws on to some kind of surface.

Without more details, I can only speculate that you probably want to create a `Bitmap` and call `Graphics.FromImage()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

[Here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial181_Capturing-screenshots-using-Csharp.html) is a complete tutorial.

Comment: The main content of the linked page doesn't load for me, but ok.